# When is the mean value function of a semimartingale continuous

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

I consider a semimartingale $(X_t)_{0 \leq t}$.I need that
$$
t \mapsto E[X_t]
$$
is continous. What kind of properties on $(X_t)$ will ensure that? I mean, if, say, $(X_t)$ has independent increments we know 
$$
E[X_t] = E[X_0] + t E[X_t-X_0]
$$
and the statement is true, but I'm clueless as to approach this issue generally.